# Configuring Azure AD Connect for an AD sub domain

Tags: active-directory, entra-id

I'm trying to configure an Azure AD Connect for a small business hosted in an OU in a sub domain in our AD.

Our AD looks something like this:

```
domain.local
-ADM.domain.local
-EDU.domain.local
-HST.domain.local
-(Server)-AADC-Corp1
--(OU)-corp1 (UPN suffix: corp1.com)
--(OU)-corp2 (UPN suffix: corp2.com)
---(Server)-AADC-Corp2
```

My thought was that I would be able to install AADConnect on a member server (AADC-Corp2) and connect it directly to the HST.domain.local domain.
However when I try to set it up I only get the option to configure it for the root domain (domain.local). I know that I can pick out the specific OU in the subdomain when configuring the Domain/OU Filtering section in AADConnect, but it seems like a lot of unnecessary traffic going through the root domain when it seems like it should be OK with just talking to the specific domain.

We already have an AADConnect set up for Corp1. It was not done by us, but by an outside consultant before I arrived. It is placed directly in the HST.domain.local domain, not in the specific OU for Corp1, and it goes via the root domain and syncs the Corp1 OU.
I saw a screenshot of an existing AADConnect where the option to add another Azure AD Domain was available. I thought that I might be able to do the same here when my initial plan backfired, but the existing AADConnect does not have the option or task of adding an additional Azure AD Domain. Do I need to have a federation server set up in order to actually have that ability?

Basically I need to set up another AADConnect for a corp in an OU. What are my best options?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/plan-connect-topologies